# How do i go about resolving this svn merge error : svn merge aborted abnormally. resolve conflicts and continue?

Tags: svn, subclipse

I was trying to merge the changes in branch A into branch B. While I was running the merge I got some error like this (don't have the exact error because I closed the console without copying the error).

> svn merge aborted abnormally. resolve conflicts and continue

I wanted to know how I should go about solving this. These are the ways I can think of.

1. Resolve the conflicts locally, commit the files to branch B and then continue the merge
2. Resolve conflicts locally, rerun the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would opt for option 2.  There's nothing preventing you from merging into a working copy with local changes.  I wouldn't commit a portion of the merge, because there's no way to determine if all of the necessary changes were applied before the original merge aborted.  So, if were me, I'd simply locally resolve the conflicts and then re-run the original merge until the merge can complete successfully.  It is possible that a merge will always have conflicts and that you simply complete the merge and address the conflicts after the merge completes.

Comment: thanks, this worked. I resolved the conflicts, then updated my code in Branch B (there were some changes that I had to update) and ran the merge again.